# Controle de acesso a rotas - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, route, middleware

Tenho algumas views que somente clientes podem acessar, e algumas que somente administradores podem acessar. O que defini no caso é o id_cliente, que se for "1" é administrador e se for qualquer outro é cliente. Controlo isso com 2 Middleware localmente, mas quando publiquei em um servidor de hospedagem recebo um erro:

> Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Routes:

```
// Rotas para administradores
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'SIST\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function()
{
    Route::get('inicio', ['as' => 'inicio','uses' => 'Admin\InicioController@index']);
});

// Rotas para clientes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'SIST\Http\Middleware\ClientMiddleware'], function ()
{
    Route::get('sist', ['as' => 'sist','uses' => 'Client\SistController@index']);
});
```

Admin Middleware:

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->id_cliente !== 1)
        {
            return redirect('/sist');
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Middleware:

```
class ClientMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {           
        $id_cliente = Auth::user()->id_cliente;

        if ($id_cliente === 1)
        {
            return redirect('/inicio');
        }else{
            $cliente = Cliente::find($id_cliente);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho muitas rotas dentro desses dois grupos e uso isso pra não deixar um cliente acessar rota de administrador digitando a URL. Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas foi o que consegui fazer. Se tiver outra forma de fazer podem me falar por favor.

Comment: Veja através da ferramenta de desenvolvimento do seu navegador qual loop está ocorrendo. Quais os dois endereços que estão recebendo redirecionamento de um para o outro. O problema pode não ter nada a ver com seu middleware, mas sim com sua zona DNS.

Comment: ao fazer login com um usuário que deveria levar para o diretório "/inicio", ele fica redirecionando infinitamente para o "/sist". O mesmo acontece se eu tento logar com usuário que realmente deveria ser direcionado para o "/sist", porem o redirecionamento nunca para.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, é como se ele não reconhecesse as condições, não sei... realmente não faço ideia. Editei a pergunta colocando o meu htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredite se quiser, mas depois de perder praticamente o dia inteiro nisso, resolvi o problema apenas trocando "`===`" por "`==`" e "`!==`" por "`!=`". Não sei o que pode ter ocasionado esse mal funcionamento na hospedagem, uma vez que localmente funcionava perfeitamente, mas foi isso!

Comment: Ow, e você saber que eu acabei errando meu script PHP. Eu ia fazer isso e acabei não fazendo na verificação dentro da middleware, pode até ver que está errada a verificação para qual link vai. Boa.

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode usar apenas uma **Route** e apenas uma **Middleware** ?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('inicio', ['as' => 'inicio','uses' => 'Admin\InicioController@index']);
    Route::get('sist', ['as' => 'sist','uses' => 'Client\SistController@index']);
});
```

Registra essa Middleware no **Kernel.php** que fica na pasta **app/Http**, nesse `array`, última linha:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic'    => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'login'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
];
```

Daí no `middleware` do `Route::group`, coloca como fiz acima: `middleware => 'admin'` ao invés daquele nome todo.

Daí no **AdminMiddleware.php** faça os dois:

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->id_cliente !== 1){
            return redirect('/sist');
        }else{
            return redirect('/inicio');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Não tem a ver com o `.htaccess`.

Comment: até tentei agora dessa maneira mas o erro continua. Vou por uma imagem na pergunta. @Zoom

Answer (score 1):

Sei que passou muito tempo, mas quis comentar para entenderem a diferença do "==" e "===", consequentemente "!=" e "!=="

Quando usamos a validação do tipo ===, se equivale a estritamente igual, o que isso quer dizer, além do valor da variável ter que ser igual o tipo também deve ser igual, exemplo:

Ex:

```
$id_cliente === 1
```

Neste caso, se sua variável for uma string, daria erro, pois está comparando um valor com uma variável que espera uma string.

Se for o caso, a comparação deveria ser assim:

```
$id_cliente === "1"
```